# Data Set/Database listing NAICS codes for U.S. firms?

Tags: data-request

I need access to a dataset that matches firms to their NAICS codes so that I can fill in some missing data in a data set I have for some research.

I was wondering if anyone on here might know of such a database or dataset I could explore?

Answer (score 1):

If NAICS are not provided in the dataset, you need a second variable, related to NAICS, to do the match. Two options are ISIC and SIC, related to industry classification. You can find the official link between these two and NAICS [here](https://www.census.gov/eos/www/naics/concordances/concordances.html). These are Excel files with the concordances, which will not be perfect (sometimes you have m-to-1 or 1-to-m matches). There are more crosswalks between classifications [here](https://www.naics.com/naics-to-sic-sic-to-naics-crosswalks/), [here](https://sites.google.com/site/alisonweingarden/links/industries), and [here](https://www.bls.gov/emp/ep_crosswalks.htm).

In terms of Stata files (if you need that), check file [C1] [here](http://www.ddorn.net/data.htm). There is also [this](http://www.nber.org/nberces/) very good NBER crosswalks (under Concordances heading), where you get SIC-NAICS crosswalks in Stata, SAS, Excel and CSV formats.

For reference, [here](https://www.xwalkcenter.org/index.php/classifications/crosswalks) you can find a mapping between SOC (occupations) and NAICS, but I am do not sure how it works, as I cannot see a 1-to-1 mapping between occupation and industry.

Finally, [here](http://faculty.som.yale.edu/peterschott/files/research/papers/hs_sic_38.pdf) there is a document describing some technical aspects of the crosswalks.

Comment: Thanks for all of this. I am familiar with the ISIC NAICS crosswalks. The reason for my question is exactly related to this crosswalk. I want to map data that contains NAICS codes to data that has ISIC codes. To do this, however, I need to fill in a lot of missing 6-digit NAICS codes since the correspondences are only at the 6-digit level. I only have information on firm names, hence the desire for a firm listing of NAICS codes.

Comment: @danny There was no way anyone could have known this from your question. The question was then incomplete and my effort/answer was totally redundant.

Comment: I asked for a dataset mapping employer name to NAICS codes for which you gave me a completely unrelated answer. The question seems pretty clear and I’ve found such a dataset but thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @student_t You could post the dataset that you found as an answer to your own question and thereby help future visitors to this site.